# Can one force a custom compiler error in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm creating a library in C# that can be used within a transaction. However, some of its methods should not be used in a transaction as they cannot be rolled back. These non-transactional methods will throw an exception at run time when used within a transaction.

The question is, can I somehow also force a compile time error when a non-transactional method is used within a transaction?

Thank you in advance.

**Update**

I should clarify that the compile time errors are for the benefit of 3rd parties who will use my library. As such any solution that requires another framework or extension would not suffice. The ideal solution would stop the project from compiling in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's impossible.

It is not possible to reliably determine at compile-time whether you're in a transaction.

Consider the following code:

```
if (...)
    thingy.BeginTransaction();
thingy.NonTransactionalMethod();
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible with C#, but it might be using Microsoft's Code Contracts.

Code Contracts:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx

You might also take a look at Spec#:
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/specsharp/

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Jonathan Dickinson for his suggestion - another option you might look into is FXCop:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(v=vs.80).aspx

http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2009/06/making-sure-fxcop-warnings-and-errors-break-the-build/

Comment: I was going to say no, but you are completely right. Something that is more fitting is FXCop - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(v=vs.80).aspx - maybe update your answer?

Comment: @Jonathan Dickinson: Thanks for the link. I'll take a look at that.